# Connect Android app to a webserver

Tags: android, performance

Some advice comrades, am thinking of developing an android app that retrieves some updates from a website. In other words when content of the website is updated the app content is also updated. I have searched google and i can't get clear answers on how to do it. Anyone tell me what do i need to do to accomplish this task. I have read about json parsing and web services but everything is not clear since am new to network apps.

Comment: If you are new, then go learn the basics. You don't need to learn the basics of the basics, but you can learn about how web services work, how HTTP works and JSON data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server is a standard http server, you'll need another server that can establish a connection with the android device.

You can implement it yourself (using TCP or UDP), or you can use the trusted Google GCM:
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

I recommend using GCM, but in either way, you'll have to make your current server, to notify the other server when it needs to send a message to any device.

Comment: Thanks JML, won't that process of having two servers slow information retrieval

Comment: Compared with what? As that is the only way I know (I've worked in a couple of applications that do what you need), using a HTTP server as on of the servers, it won't be slower than other methods.
You could do everything in a single server, with a "long lived" TCP / UDP connection, but it's really hard to keep that connection stable (as android has lots of optimizations when talking about connectivity)
I recommend you using whatever server you want, plus the implementation of GCM, as it's the standard way to achive this behaviour